# How to change statusbar font color?

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I applied 2 themes in my app, For day & night mode. but into night mode status bar background color change but status bar font color not changed.

My status bar color is **Black** but, font color also black. I want to change my status bar font color.

i want to need **white** color text like below image.

[image]

If Anyone has the best solution for it then please comment your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

//code By Gymkhana Studio

```
Window w = this.getWindow();
w.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
w.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: not work in my case, i already applyed many solutions

Comment: this.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(0xFFE0E0E0);

Comment: This should change your status bar colour to light grey, should work for only a specific activity. If you intend to change the entire status bar colour, edit the colorPrimaryDark color in colors.xml in res/values/- folder

Comment: I think I finally understand your question.

Comment: `public static void setLightStatusBar(View view,Activity activity){


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                int flags = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
                flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
                view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE); 
            }
}`

Comment: I applied your solution but its make status bar color change, but I want to change font color, I want to make a black status bar with white font and icon.